# Compare 2 numbers using printf() java

Tags: java, compare, printf

This is for a school assignment. I need to compare int varible "one" with int varible "two" and output the lesser value. I'm supposed to do it using printf though, any advice on this? Thanks!

Comment: How about converting each integer value into a fixed-length string of digits, then compare the strings? You should be able to figure out where `printf()` comes into play with this approach.

Comment: Double-check the details of your assignment -- if you're in a beginner course, I suspect that you're supposed to compare 1 and 2, (vs "one" and "two") -- a much easier problem to solve.

Comment: Thanks, everyone! Yes, I figured out I was supposed to use the printf inside an IF statement.

Answer (score 1):

I have to assume they mean that you have to print the lesser one using printf, in which case you just need to have some simple if checks and print using the [normal formatting rules.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

If they instead mean you can only have one line in your main, that prints out the variable then you either need to use a ternary statement of `condition ? statement : default` or make a method to compare the two.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yeah I realized they probably meant an if statement and have the printf inside it.